# WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 Rename File on Destination Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am running WSO2 ESB 4.8.0, which I **can not** upgrade, I am also inexperienced with ESB, but have searched and tried many things.

I have a Sequence that uses VFS SMB to send files to a downstream system. The files are sent successfully, but sometimes the downstream system starts processing the file before ESB has completed the send. I want to prevent this.

One solution would be to send with a different extension (.tmp or .sending) then do a rename after the transmission. I can't figure this out. I have tried installing FileConnector V2 but get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/wso2/carbon/connector/FileListZip : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I believe this is because 4.8 uses Java 1.7 and the Connector requires Java 1.8, and when I try creating a Sequence I can't see the File mediator as an option (should it even be an option?), the Connector is also Enabled.

Please point me in the right direction or tips what I should be searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same on 4.8.1 because FileConnecor v2 needs java 1.8. There's a version 1 of the file connector which works in 4.8.1. Unfortunately I cannot find it in the wso2 store anymore. Maybe you have to look somewhere else.

When I open a proxy in the design view of the admin console, I can see e.g. fileconnector.copy in it.

Answer (score 0):

File connector version 2 only supports for latest ESB's like ESB 5.0.0 ESB 4.9.0 as it is mentioned in the download page. The older version of the file connector (version 1.0.0) supports ESB 4.8.1 but it is deprecated. [1].

You can follow below steps to build the connector.

```
git clone https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-file.git
cd esb-connector-file
git tag
git checkout tags/org.wso2.carbon.connector.fileconnector-1.0.0
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Once you build successfully, you can find the zip file inside the "PATH/esb-connector-file/target" directory. Here we have attached the fileconnector-connector-1.0.0.zip fileconnector-connector-1.0.0.zip which we got after building the code and it works fine without any error.

If you use file connector V2 in ESB 4.8.1 you will get some error.

If you want to use file connector V2 in ESB 4.8.1 you have to follow the below steps.

We were able to deploy file connector V2 by adding the commons-net orbit bundle commons-net_3.3.0.wso2v1.jar in to a ESB 4.8.1 instance. We received this jar from ESB 4.9.0. (/repository/components/plugins). Please find the steps we followed to test the commons-net_3.3.0.wso2v1.jar below:

```
Placed the attached commons-net_3.3.0.wso2v1.jar r in <ESB_HOME>/repository/components/dropins
Start the ESB 4.8.1
Uploaded the file connector V2 and enabled it.
```

[2017-04-14 19:35:15,686] INFO - LibraryArtifactDeployer Synapse Library named '{org.wso2.carbon.connector}fileconnector' has been deployed from file : /home/hariprasath/Documents/support/TRIVADISAGDEV-6/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/deployment/server/synapse-libs/fileconnector-connector-2.0.10.zip
[2017-04-14 19:35:26,721] INFO - SynapseImportFactory Successfully created Synapse Import: fileconnector

[1] - http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2016-May/063761.html